# Identifying a catenary

Tags: calculus

A catenary curve $y = f(x) = \dfrac{1}{a} \cosh(a x) $ is shifted horizontally and vertically, such that its equation becomes

$y = f(x) = y_1 + \dfrac{1}{a} ( \cosh(a(x - x_1))-1 ) $

Subject to the conditions

$f(0) = h_1 = 10 $

$f(15) = h_2 = 20$

And the length of the curve from $x=0$ to $x=15$ is equal to $30$.

That is,

$ 30 = \displaystyle \int_0^{15} \sqrt{1 + f'(x)^2 } dx $

Find the minimum point $(x_1, y_1)$ on the curve.

I was able to find the solution numerically using the multivariate Newton-Raphson method, but was wondering if there is a closed form solution.

I got $a = 0.276243 , x_1 = 6.2454, y_1 = 3.13638 $

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was only able to come up with a partial answer, but it confirms your calculation of $a$ and suggests that a closed form (at least for $a$) doesn't seem likely.  Starting from your two given given values on the catenary

\begin{align}
f(0)&=\frac{1}{a}(\cosh{(a(-x_1))}-1)+y_1 &= 10\\
f(15)&=\frac{1}{a}(\cosh{(a(15-x_1))}-1)+y_1 &= 20
\end{align}

and subtracting will eliminate $y_1$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a}(\cosh{(a(15-x_1))}-1) -\frac{1}{a}(\cosh{(a(-x_1))}-1)&=10\\
&\frac{1}{a}\cosh{(a(15-x_1))}-\frac{1}{a}\cosh{(ax_1)}&=10
\end{align}
Then working on the arc length and noting that $f'(x)=\sinh(a(x-x_1))$, so that equation becomes
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{15} \sqrt{1 + \sinh^2(a(x-x_1))} dx &=30\\
&\int_0^{15} \sqrt{\cosh^2(a(x-x_1))} dx &=30\\
&\int_0^{15} \cosh(a(x-x_1)) dx &=30\\
&\frac{1}{a}\sinh{(a(x-x_1))}\bigr|_0^{15}&=30\\
&\frac{1}{a}\sinh{(a(15-x_1))}-\frac{1}{a}\sinh{(a(-x_1))}&=30\\
&\frac{1}{a}\sinh{(a(15-x_1))}+\frac{1}{a}\sinh{(ax_1)}&=30\\
\end{align}
We're almost ready to make some progress on simplification as we have two very similar looking equations involving $\cosh$ and $\sinh$.  If we add (resp. subtract) those together, we will get equations involving only exponentials.

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a}e^{a(15-x_1)}-\frac{1}{a}e^{-x_1}&=40\\
&\frac{1}{a}e^{-x_1}(e^{15a}-1)&=40\\
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a}e^{x_1}-\frac{1}{a}e^{-a(15-x_1)}&=20\\
&\frac{1}{a}e^{x_1}(1-e^{-15a})&=20\\
\end{align}
Multiplying the two exponential equations obtained will give us an equation involving only $a$(!)
$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{a^2}(e^{15a}-1)(1-e^{-15a})&=800\\
&\frac{1}{a^2}(e^{15a}-1-1+e^{-15a})&=800\\
&\frac{1}{a^2}(2\cosh{(15a)}-2)&=800\\
&\frac{1}{a^2}(\cosh{(15a)}-1)&=400\\
\end{align}
$$

Approximating a solution for the last equation (or asking WolframAlpha) gives $a\approx0.276243$ in agreement with your result.  Perhaps there are nicer expressions for $x_1$ and $y_1$, but looking at the expression for $a$ wouldn't suggest that.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @sharding4's answer, we can obtain an "almost" analytical solution for $a$ using his/her last equation

$$\frac{1}{a^2}(\cosh{(15a)}-1)=400$$ Consider that we look for the zero of function
$$f(a)=\cosh{(15a)}-400a^2-1$$
Assuming that the $1$ does not contribute for much
$$\cosh{(15a)}-400a^2=0  \qquad  \sim \quad \frac12 e^{15a}=400a^2\implies \qquad a_0=-\frac{2}{15} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{3}{8 \sqrt{2}}\right)$$ where appears the second branch of Lambert function; This is not too bad since, numerically, $a_0=0.272092$.

Now, the first iteration of Newton method gives
$$a_1=a_0+\frac15\,\,\frac {1600a_0^2-1 } {1920000 a_0^4-256000 a_0^3-3 }$$

Numerically, this gives $a_1=0.276472$ while the exact solution is
$0.276243$

Accepting as a solution this explicit expression of $a$ we abtain explict expressions for $(x_1,y_1)$.